# as3 How can a function use variable from another function?

Tags: actionscript-3

Obviously I'm new to as3...Can someone please explain to me how I can use the variable from one function in another function?

For example:

```
function init():void {
 var test:Number = 1;
}

init();

trace(test);
```

I get an error:

```
1120: Access of undefined property test.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either define the variable outside of the function:

```
var test:Number = 0;

function init():void
{
    test = 1;
}

init();

trace(test); //output: 1
```

Or `return` the value from the `init()` function like this:

```
function init():Number
{
    var test:Number = 1;
    return test;
}

trace(init()); //output: 1
```

---

### Note:

Normally you'd just do:

```
function init():Number
{
    return 1;
}
```

But I did the above for the sake of explanation.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that's the quickest answer you've replied me so far! i've been timing you lol

Comment: Lol. Hopefully my boss hasn't ;)